# Is it possible to control the phone's vibrator?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, vibration

I need to control the phone's vibration functionality when the user taps certain elements of my app's UI. I can't figure out how to get access the vibrator though. Is it possible? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible - see [Vibration Device class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.phone.devices.notification.vibrationdevice.aspx). This code should vibrate your phone:

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VibrationDevice device = VibrationDevice.GetDefault();
    if (device != null) device.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```

The above code should work for *WP8.1 WinRT*, for *WP8.1 Silverlight* take a look [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206994(v=vs.105).aspx) and use [VibrateController class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.devices.vibratecontroller(v=vs.105).aspx).